# Calculate two dates by using DATEDIFF with the date form like dd-mm-yy in SQL

Tags: sql

When a user calculates the average date between 2017-06-25 and 2017-06-15 in SQL.

It can use this code

`SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(day, "2017-06-25", "2017-06-15"));`

But how can I use `DATEDIFF` in **dd-mm-yy** kind of date form like 25-06-17 and 25-06-17 ?

Comment: Date your question with the database you are using.  If you have a string in a different format, then you need to convert it to a date.

Comment: Please add the relevant database tag to your question as it helps others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query with convert :

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(day, convert(datetime, '23-10-16', 5), convert(datetime, '25-06-17', 5) ))
```

Comment: what the " 5 " is for?

Comment: It's mean dd-mm-yy Italian , this convert take number 5 to do the job.